# How to find the common elements in two lists? Best solution in terms of time complexity and space complexity

Tags: list, sorting, optimization, time, duplicates

I have two lists and elements in each list is a employee object. Every employee has an id(int) and name (string) say.

Both the lists may have some common employees and those need to be given some special privilege. The task is to find those common ones.

One solution can be to use nested loops but that would be O(n^2). Another one can be to sort both of them on employee-id and that would be O(nlogn) and then using logic similar to merge. We traverse both of them simultaneously and when we find employee with same id we capture it. What is the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get the intersection of the two linked lists. For this you would have to first sort them O(nlogn), n being the size of the largest one. Then you build a list containing the common elements: start withe the head of the lists and advance the pointers according to employee ID.

```
if (list1.ID == list2.ID)
{
  copyToNewList(list1.ID);
}
else
if(list1.ID > list2.ID)
{
   lsit2 = list2->next;
}
else
{
  lsit1 = list1->next;
}
```

You have to consider the case when you finish going through one of the lists and the other one still has elements - but you get the idea.

If space is not your concern, and you are only worried about speed, you can allocate an array of size max ID you expect to have in any of the lists. In this array, each index will represent the ID. Now you can scan the first array and for each elements `array[ID] = 1`. Then you scan the second list and:

if (array[ID] == 1)
    array[ID] = 3;
else
    array[ID] = 2;
Now your array can tell you which elements are common, which are only in list 1 and which only in list 2 - if you need this info - in O(max(m,n));

Please mind that this solution will be efficient for a limited number of ID's - if you expect to have ID's in the order of tens or hundreds of thousands, not only will it be space inefficient, retrieving the data from the array will also take a long time.

Edit:
Actually if you use a hash table instead of an array you get a more space efficient solution and it's still O(max(m,n))

Comment: Thats what I have also thought of. I need to know the optimum solution. I also thought of storing the nodes of the first linked list in a hash table while traversing it. Then for every node in second list we can search the hashtable. If it is there it is common. I think in that case time complexity will be O(n). Isn't it?

Comment: Not really: storing the nodes of the first list in a hashTable O(n), traversing the second list and searching for the nodes in the hashTable O(n*m);

Comment: I edited my answer to include a faster, more memory consuming solution.

Comment: @Pandrei - I think that getting an element from a hashtable is usually considered to be constant time - O(1). Just compute the hash value and look there, assuming there are minimal clashes. So, if putting into & getting from a hashtable are both constant time, this will be O(n+m) - because you need to traverse both lists and perform constant-time operation for each element.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia only a few problems with your solution: first the question clearly states it's dealing with lists not any other data structures. Second, for this particular case a hash table won't help because you still have to scan all the elements (and the hash table has a much larger memory footprint)

Comment: @Pandrei - I don't think I get what you mean. Here's the code I have in mind. Am I wrong in thinking that this is O(n+m)? [Adding n nodes to hash table [ O(n) ], followed by checking for m nodes in hash table [ O(m) ] = O(n+m)   Sorry for not being able to format code correctly in a comment.

Comment: `Set<String> listAElements = new HashSet<String>();
 for (String element : listA) {
  listAElements.add(element);
 }
  
 List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (String element : listB) {
  if (listAElements.contains(element)) {
   commonElements.add(element);
  }
 }`